# Updating the column values using previous row

Tags: r, data.table

I want to use the `data.table` functions to update a column's value by referring the value its value in previous rows. Here is an example

```
> DT<-data.table(id=1:2,x=1:10,y=1)
```

I already knew `data.table` can refer to previous rows in a way like below:

```
> DT[,z:=cumsum(y),keyby=id]
> DT[]
    id  x y z
 1:  1  1 1 1
 2:  1  3 1 2
 3:  1  5 1 3
 4:  1  7 1 4
 5:  1  9 1 5
 6:  2  2 1 1
 7:  2  4 1 2
 8:  2  6 1 3
 9:  2  8 1 4
10:  2 10 1 5
```

However, the next example is not working, where trying to create a `Fibonacci` series using previous values in column `y` to update itself. It seems data.table is not using a loop to perform the calculation iteratively. Can anyone tell me how to solve this kind problem using `data.table` elegantly?

```
> DT[,y:=shift(y,1,fill=0)+shift(y,2,fill=0),]
> DT[]
    id  x y z
 1:  1  1 0 1
 2:  1  3 1 2
 3:  1  5 2 3
 4:  1  7 2 4
 5:  1  9 2 5
 6:  2  2 0 1
 7:  2  4 1 2
 8:  2  6 2 3
 9:  2  8 2 4
10:  2 10 2 5
```

What I actually want is below (column `y` is updated):

```
    id  x y z
 1:  1  1 1 1
 2:  1  3 1 2
 3:  1  5 2 3
 4:  1  7 3 4
 5:  1  9 5 5
 6:  2  2 1 1
 7:  2  4 1 2
 8:  2  6 2 3
 9:  2  8 3 4
10:  2 10 5 5
```

Comment: Are you specifically after a `fibonacci` sequence, or a more general answer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm looking for more general answers for this type of problem, 'fibonacci' is just an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generating Fibonacci numbers is by definition a sequential problem, which we could solve in `data.table` by defining a custom function that works with a `for.loop` under the hood.

```
# Define function
fibon <- function(x) {
  for(i in 3:length(x)) x[i] = x[i-1] + x[i-2] 
  return(x)
}

# Plug into data.table
DT[,y := fibon(y), by = id]
> DT
#   id  x y z
#1:  1  1 1 1
#2:  1  3 1 2
#3:  1  5 2 3
#4:  1  7 3 4
#5:  1  9 5 5
#6:  2  2 1 1
#7:  2  4 1 2
#8:  2  6 2 3
#9:  2  8 3 4
#10: 2 10 5 5
```